# Is there any alternative to ASP.NET MVC OutputCache without sliding expiration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I have a public static/singleton class with IsDataModified() which is affected by change in database, file, type of user, api, etc, processes immidiately, just returns a bool variable.

The frequency of modification of output data varies extremely from a minute to months, so I won't use sliding expiration, instead let duration be MAX or infinite.

But what I'm looking for is

1. List item
2. request by browser
3. MVC filter to check if cache missing or IsDataModified()

   1. Update cache and return
   2. Else return existing cache

I tried extending OutputCache, setting duration to very large number, but once the page is cached the filters are not triggered.

Basically I do not want the duration specified to be the deciding factor as to when cache will expire, rather IsDataModified() should be the deciding factor.

One approach I think is to create a simple filter and use output cache or similar object through code behind, but I could not find OutputCacheAttribute  giving a cached viewresult.

Is this possible? Please suggest.

Comment: Very specifically server side caching

Comment: look into memcache

Comment: memcache is great, trying ObjectCache that should suffice my needs if only I'm able to pass variable/non-primitive datatype to filter

Answer (score 0):

So I have implemented a solution built on top of Redis (memcache is a lot messier).   I use an open source Redis Output Cache provider which basically creates a key corresponding to the URL of the page.   Whenever the underlying data is changed for one of the pages I remove the value from Redis where the key maches some pattern.  (My data sort of has a hierarchy so I delete the cache for more items when it is a piece of data from the parent that is updated).

Using a similar approach of deleting the cached page when the data is updated would probably also work for you.   On a side note,  I am thinking of trying to change my process so that I have a background service that creates the page when data is updated and replaces the cache so that the first users don't have a slow response after the page is first removed from the cache.